# May I ask the source code related to Embedded Python/Numpy?

Tags: monetdb

I want to learn about the code that's related to Embedded Python/Numpy and how the optimizer will handle the Python UDF. May I ask the related source code?

Answer (score 1):

The Python UDFs source is here: https://github.com/MonetDB/MonetDB/tree/master/sql/backends/monet5/UDF/pyapi3

Python UDFs are handled just as UDFs in other languages (SQL, R, MAL) by the optimizers.